# Is there a classification of immersions of an n-sphere into a compact n-manifold without boundary?

Tags: differential-topology

Is there a classification of smooth immersions of an n-sphere into a compact n-manifold without boundary? I'm interested in the case where the dimensions of the two manifolds are the same. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any such immersion is a covering map onto a connected component. The point is an immersion of closed connected $n$-manifolds is a covering map.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek Thank you!